# how to remove the last two zero?

Tags: php, zen-cart

I have a function called `zen_get_products_discount_price_qty($new_products->fields['products_id'])` which outputs this: `$8.0000`.
I want to turn the `$8.0000` into `$8.00`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$value = '$8.0000';
$value = str_replace('$', '', $value);
$value = number_format($value, 2);
echo $value;
```

https://www.php.net/number_format

It's important to use number_format to get correctly values. The function substr() only delete the last two zeros. The function number_format() round the number.

```
number_format(8.1199, 2); // == 8.12 - correct
substr(8.1199, 0, -2); // == 8.11 - false!
```

Answer (score 2):

use [number_format](http://php.net/number_format) function

Answer (score 2):

```
   $output = zen_get_products_discount_price_qty($new_products->fields['products_id']);
   $output =  substr($output,0,-2);
```

Comment: The function substr() is not the best solution. It didn't round the number!

Comment: @Scoutman  value is prefixed with '$'  hence it not gonna use it for mathematics operation probably just want to echo it out hence substr suits here .

Answer (score 1):

first remove $ then use round() function.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf('$%.02f', 8.0000); // $8.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Or preg_replace :)

echo preg_replace("/^\$(\d+?)(?:.\d*)?$/", "\$$1.00", '$8.0000');

Output: $8.00

Answer (score 0):

**DON'T** use any substr(), printf(), number_format() etc. solutions. They don't take care of currencies other than USD where there might be different display requirements. Use instead Zen Cart global $currencies object:

```
$currencies->format($my_price);
```

Check includes/classes/currencies.php for reference.